# Adding html code instead of plain text to ul with appendchild or other method?

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, innerhtml, appendchild

```js
document.getElementById('addplace').addEventListener('click', function() {
    addplace();
  });

function addplace () {
  var node = document.createElement("li");                 // Create a <li> node
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("<b>Waypoint</b>");         // Create a text node
  node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
  document.getElementById("waypoints").appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="addplace" value="Add One!">  
<ul id="waypoints">
</ul>
```

I need this to make the html code work in each new li. I tried innerHTML as well and was only able to add plain text. How to make "Waypoint" bold instead of it showing the text "Waypoint" enclosed by b tags?

It's specifically for adding a new Google Places autocomplete field and an image of an "x" to delete the li so i'm looking for a solution that can pass values / be JavaScript friendly for the rest of my application mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319158/replace-selection-list-with-places-autocomplete-in-google-maps-directions-with-w).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a text node, create a node for `<b>` tag and set its text content.

```
function addplace () {
  var node = document.createElement("li");                 // Create a <li> node
  var textNode = document.createElement("b"); //create a <b> tag
  textNode.textContent = "Waypoint"; //set <b> tag's text
  node.appendChild(textnode);  //Append the <b> tag                            
  document.getElementById("waypoints").appendChild(node);
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ujkpv6gr/)

If you want to set different html elmenets inside of `li` more than a `<b>` element, then you could use the below,

```
function addplace() {
  var node = document.createElement("li"); // Create a <li> node
  node.innerHTML = "<b>waypoints</b>"               
  document.getElementById("waypoints").appendChild(node);
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ujkpv6gr/1/)

Comment: thanks i need it to work for html in general not just b tags. though i will play around with this and see if it works for an input tag and also for an input+img.

Comment: Thanks Rajaprabhu. I am able to add <input /> without any attributes but when i try <input class="test" type="text"/> for example then the button ceases to create the new li elements. Any idea why that happens or how to workaround it? I could post as a new question if that's a better approach.

Comment: @javaandy You could create a new question for that, as it is out of scope for the current question. And share a link of that question to me if you want.

Comment: Thanks here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36532484/innerhtml-or-other-method-append-li-to-ul-with-input-including-attributes

Comment: @javaandy I answered that question. Does that helps you?

Comment: yes thanks will approve answer once allowed by stackoverflow.